# Is isomath clashing with siunitx? If so, how to resolve italics vs upright in units?

Tags: siunitx, isomath

I'm using both the siunitx and isomath packages. I'm not sure whether there's a clash between those packages when it comes to Greek symbols in units. Indeed, isomath italicize capital Greek symbols (as it should to stay ISO-80000-2 compliant), while units should be upright. Therefore the ohm symbol Omega appears italicized when using \si{\ohm} while it should be upright; am I wrong? If not, how could I fix this issue? I.e. I'd like Omega to appear italicized when it's not used via siunitx, but I want it to be upright when using siunitx.

Edit: By creating a minimal example I realized that it isn't a clash between isomath and siunitx but cmbright and siunitx (I think!). Here's the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif font type.
\usepackage[margin = 2.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{cmbright}

%%% fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
%%%

\begin{document}

Here I expect an upright Greek letter: \si{\ohm}. However it is italicized.

Here I expect an italicized Greek letter: $\Omega$. Right now, it works fine.

\end{document}
```

If I remove the line invoking cmbright, I get the behavior that I expect. But I do need that package. I use it so that the math fonts are sans serif and similar to my text fonts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have to provide a suitable definition for the symbol here: it's not possible to guess every possible font combination.

Comment: @dexteritas, I have edited my question to include a MWE. Maybe it needs further edits to display an image and also to modify the title since apparently the culprit isn't isomath but cmbright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `isomath` after `cmbright`.  Sometimes, package loading order makes a difference, especially when fonts are involved.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif font type.
\usepackage[margin = 2.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{isomath}

%%% fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
%%%

\begin{document}

Here I expect an upright Greek letter: \si{\ohm}. However it is italicized.

Here I expect an italicized Greek letter: $\Omega$. Right now, it works fine.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As I commented , however, the `cmbright` seems to be wiped out by the later loading of `lmodern`.  One might, thus, have meant it this way.  In either case, though, the `isomath` should be loaded later than `cmbright`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%%% fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif font type.
\usepackage[margin = 2.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{isomath}


\begin{document}

Here I expect an upright Greek letter: \si{\ohm}. However it is italicized.

Here I expect an italicized Greek letter: $\Omega$. Right now, it works fine.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem, thank you very much! I'd appreciate a very brief explanation of why this work. I'm guessing it has to do with cmbright undoing things isomath does?

Comment: @no_choice99 *I'm guessing it has to do with cmbright undoing things isomath does?*  Without knowing the specifics, the answer is "yes."  In general, one would want to define the math font families (in this case `cmbright`) before redefining how those fonts behave in various math circumstances (which is what `isomath` does).

Comment: @no_choice99 Of course, it would seem that `lmodern` clobbers the `cmbright` stuff, so I am not sure where exactly you want the answer to go...

Comment: Thanks again for your comment and edit in the answer. I'm confused on which fonts looks better now in your 2 displays of the fixed problem. In other words I'm confused on whether to load lmodern before the other 2 packages or if I should load it last.

Comment: @no_choice99 My point is only that loading `lmodern` last would seem to eliminate altogether any effect of loading `cmbright`, since `lmodern` defines its own set of `sffamily` fonts.

Comment: Ok, perfect! I'll load it first then, like you did in your 2nd example. By the way, nice answer.